# Externally Manipulating a C# String of Different Length

Tags: c#

I have a pretty unique problem I need to be solved.

I have a compiled C# application, and I need the ability to replace certain strings in it. Now, I know if I want to replace the strings with my own strings of the same length, I can simply change the bytes. The problem is, some of the strings may be shorter than needed, and I need to null-terminate that somehow.

If this was C, I could just add a null byte after I added the string I wanted to replace, but in C# obviously null bytes are included in the string, and this will cause problems for my application

Do any of you have a solution for how to do this?

Thank you

Comment: You're probably going to be better off reverse engineering the code with some decompiler, then compiling it again. All in all, if you dont have the source, you're in for a big headache.

Comment: Can you make it so the strings you need to change are in the application's config file instead of trying to change the bits in the code?

Comment: "I have a compiled C# application", is that all you have? Or do you have the source code somewhere? If you can't modify the original program, this is probably going to get ugly.

Comment: It seems you would need to parse and understand the "#US" stream in the metadata.  See [here](http://www.visualcplusdotnet.com/visualcplusdotnet5a.html): "The string is stored as a Unicode string (0xa bytes long) prefixed with the length of the entire entry.".  Also maybe see [here](http://codingwithspike.wordpress.com/2012/09/01/building-a-net-disassembler-part-4-reading-the-metadata-tables-in-the-stream/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be able to do this using some free tools. One is Telerik's [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx), and the other is a plugin for JustDecompile that allows you to fairly easily edit existing assemblies. The plugin is [Reflixil](http://reflexil.net/). You can download and install it by using the plugin configuration feature from within JustDecompile.

To see if it worked, I did a little test with a simple winform application I have. I dragged the exe file, dropped it onto JustDecompile, and it loaded the exe assembly. I then clicked on Reflexil under the Plugins menu to enable the plugin pane. I clicked on a method that had a literal string I wanted to change as a test.

[image]

As a test, I tried to change "seconds" to "seconds elapsed", purposefully choosing a longer string length. In the Reflexil pane, I found the IL code that referenced the literal:

[image]

right clicked on that line, and selected Edit. That allowed me to just type in a different string. After editing it, the line showed up like this in the Reflexil pane:

[image]

I then went to the left pane, right clicked on my assembly, and selected Reflexil from the pop-up menu, and selected Save and Reload from the menu under that. I then ran my program, and low and behold, this is how the text I changed showed up on the form:

[image]

So, all in all it was pretty easy, and seemed to let me do exactly what you're asking for, i.e. directly edit strings in an existing C#/.Net assembly.

Answer (score 1):

If you were going to modify the program that is already compiled, you could include sockets. That way the program could get a request to modify a string. Or to accept commands from the command line while its running. But Im guessing that you dont want to touch the compiled program. If it was a cstring then your memory edit would work (provided you knew the location).

Answer (score 1):

The way that strings are stored in C# compiled code is different from the way that C++ does it.  I have not actually looked at the bits, but I believe that the strings are stored in the executable the same way they are stored in memory.  This means that someplace there are a set of bytes that tells the system how long the string is and the string is not actually null terminated.  For you to get this to work the way you think you would need to find those bytes and change them to reflect the length.

If you have access to the code, you might want to change the code so it uses values from a config file instead of values stored in the code.